# vb.net splashscreen

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, splash-screen

I am creating a Windows Form Application using VB.Net.

I have to show a splashscreen with a GIF image (loading) in a picturebox. Simultaneously perform an operation on a form. So I am hiding the form and displaying the splashscreen.

If I make the thread sleep, the GIF image doesn't animate.

Need suggestions to implement the above!

Comment: Why do you need to make the thread sleep?

Comment: I want to set the splashscreen duration for a certain amount of time, say 5 seconds. So, I make the thread sleep but it stops the GIF image too. Need an alternative way for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your splash screen to automatically close after a fixed amount of time, just use a timer.

```
Public Class SplashScreen
    Private WithEvents _timer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()

    Private Sub FormVb1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        _timer.Interval = 5000  ' five seconds
        _timer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub _timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _timer.Tick
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where should I include this code?
I have a Report.vb form (which needs to be hidden while splashscreen is showed)

Comment: The example code shows the code inside the splash screen form's code.  But, you could modify it easily to do this same thing from the Report form instead.